# N/A error while using the correct VLookup formula to get value from other sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

In excel, I was trying to get fund value of a particular mutual fund by using VLookup to search another sheet. In the process, I am getting N/A error even if the VLookup formula seems correct.
[image: The sheet from where I am trying to get the "Net Asset Value" taking "Scheme Code" as input search string]

The below screenshot is of the sheet with the VLookup excel formula:

[image: The sheet with vlookup formula used]

Is there any issues with the vlookup formula that I am using here. 
`=VLOOKUP(D4,Sheet1!$A$5072:$E$5075,5,FALSE)`
I have tried many version of the vlookup but to no avail. Could anyone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry..my bad...I have pasted the corrected screenshot but still it gives the error.

Comment: N/A means the lookup didn't find a match.  Check for numbers vs text, leading or trailing spaces

Comment: Agree with Chris.  I use VLOOKUP frequently.  I will often just put a quick equals formula to test the values, eg =D4=A5073 (with the appropriate sheet names).  If you get FALSE as the result then the data doesn't match and you need to look at Chris's suggestion.  You will need to "clean" your data so they match.

Comment: It is a case of matching number vs text. When I check "=TYPE(A5073)" in the lookup array cell, I get "2" as result which means "text", while doing "=TYPE(D4)" in lookup item sheet gives "1" meaning "number". I might have to find a way to clean this data first & then check. Thanks @chrisneilsen

Comment: @lib23 yes, cleaning the data is the best option.  But a quick and dirty work aroubd would be to use `=INDEX($E$5072:$E$5075,MATCH(D4,VALUE($A$5072:$A$5075),0))` or `=XLOOKUP(D4,VALUE($A$5072:$A$5075),$E$5072:$E$5075,,0,1)`

Comment: That worked really well. Thanks @chrisneilsen once again for the rescue. How do I upvote your comment? If this was an answer, I could have accepted it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning the data is the best option, so that both values are either all text, or all numbers.

But a quick and dirty work aroubd would be to use to convert the text to numbers

```
=INDEX($E$5072:$E$5075,MATCH(D4,VALUE($A$5072:$A$5075),0))
```

or

```
=XLOOKUP(D4,VALUE($A$5072:$A$5075),$E$5072:$E$5075,,0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Chris Neilsen that this is most likely a case of different formatting between the lookup item vs lookup array.  The left alignment implies that both are formatted as text.  Given this, just double check that both indeed are formatted as text vs. someone left-aligning a column of numbers.

Let us know if that doesn't solve the problem and we can walk you through replacing this formula with an Index+Match formula.